# Check date if exist in this year or not in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdateformatter, date-format

I googled and found many link which compares 2 dates but my scenario is bit different and I am unable to found in google. I want to compare date either exist in this year or not.
I have date like in this format.
 **2016-01-20T06:19:27** 
so If below than current year then I will use this format

```
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
```

and If exist in this year then will use

```
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
```

(to remove year), and in future no chance date will exist.
So need solutions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString * date = [dictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
 NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *myDate = [dateformat dateFromString:date];

 [dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

 NSString *strYear=[dateformat stringFromDate:myDate];

  if([strYear isEqualToString:[dateformat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]){
     [dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
     NSString *strDate=[dateformat stringFromDate:myDate];
     NSLog(@"%@",strDate);
  }
  else{
    [dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
    NSString *strDate=[dateformat stringFromDate:myDate];
    NSLog(@"%@",strDate);
  }
```

Comment: I am going to try this but don't you think so that 2015 and 2016 should be get from code (to fetch current year from code instead of statically mention)?

Comment: Thanks this Worked!!

Comment: See my final function under OR

Comment: if works then accept answer by checkMark. so it can be helpful for other.

Answer (score 4):

`NSCalender` has very powerful methods to do any kind of date math:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-01-20T06:19:27";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
BOOL isInCurrentYear = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] compareDate:date toDate:[NSDate date] toUnitGranularity:NSCalendarUnitYear] == NSOrderedSame;
formatter.dateFormat = isInCurrentYear ?  @"dd MMM" : @"dd MMM yyyy";
NSString *formattedDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```